# MySQL query r.e covering index with Primary Key

Tags: mysql

I have the following table (there are more columns in the real one).

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`j_data` (
`j_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`j_name` VARCHAR(80) NULL DEFAULT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (`j_id`));
```

We regularly run queries where the main column used is the PK, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM j_data WHERE j_id = 123;
```

But we are now looking to run a lot of queries like:

```
SELECT j_id FROM j_data WHERE j_name = xxx;
```

Would this benefit from a covering index on `j_name` and `j_id`.

```
ADD INDEX `j_name_id` (`j_name` ASC, `j_id` ASC);
```

Or would an index on `j_name` only suffice? It's quite a large table so I don't want to spend time adding the index if it is unlikely to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:  Yes.

Long answer:

You are using InnoDB, correct?  (Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE j_data` to find out what the Engine is.)

In InnoDB, each "secondary index" (contrast "primary key") silently contains a copy of the primary key.

So...  `INDEX(j_name)` happens to be identical to `INDEX(j_name, j_id)`.

Tip:  At some point you will realize that prefixing all columns with the table name ("j_") is unnecessary clutter.

Comment: yes, it is INNODB. I assumed that was the case, but though it best to check these things. Sometimes MySQL doesn't work in the obvious way. cheers,

Comment: @IGGt - Many vendors use a "rownum" to uniquely identify and locate each row in the table.  MyISAM uses a byte address into the .MYD file.  InnoDB uses the `PRIMARY KEY`; thereby forcing the PK to exist and be unique.  Which of these is the "obvious way"?  That depends on your perspective.  The corollary (for InnoDB only) is that secondary keys include the PK; hence this discussion.